# To get GMSPlace without using didAutocompleteWithPlace in swift

Tags: swift, gmsplace

In my swift application there is a "textfield" for searching place using "GooglePlaces".I want to make the place default to "Los Angeles".So if the user is not selecting any place then the app will take the default address.So how to get the "GMSPlace" of "Los Angeles", where the filter type should be "geocode"?